# Multiple Vars for DateDiff VBA

Tags: excel, vba, datediff

I have a VBA script at the moment that reads in 6 values as integers.  3 values for date, month, and year and 3 of the same type from a different location.  I'd like to take the values and check if there has been more than a year to pass between them.  DateDiff seems like the easiest way to handle this, however that function reads in the values as one DateValue (ie March 20, 2015) and my values are returned individually (08,08,2015).
I wrote a function that stores each value into a var and then using those individually I concat them into a format that DateValue can use.
This works, however I am curious if there is another(better) way to handle this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `DateSerial(2015,3,4)` will return the date for 3/4/2015, and with both of your dates in that format, you can subtract the one date from the other, and if the (absolute value of the) difference is > 365 then you know that they are over a year apart.

```
Dim A As Date
A = DateSerial(2015, 3, 4)
Dim B As Date
B = DateSerial(2014, 3, 2)
Dim C As Integer
C = Abs(A - B)
MsgBox C & " days between"
```